# How do I apply FlowJS annotations to a Sequelize model?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js, flowtype

I am attempting to use FlowJS together with Sequelize in a backend node project. However, there is no specific FlowJS documentation for how to annotate the data types involved, and I am getting code that works but also throws a lot of type errors.

I have a complete working version of this demo project [on github](https://github.com/savannidgerinel/stackoverflow-sequelize-flow).

We start out with a basic model definition. I've been playing a lot of Stellaris recently, so I'm thinking grand galactic strategy here.

```
// @flow

import Sequelize, { type Model } from "sequelize";

export type Empire = {
  name: string,
  species: string,
  homeworld: string
};

const EmpireModel = (sequelize: Sequelize): Class<Model<Empire>> =>
  sequelize.define("empires", {
    name: { type: Sequelize.STRING, allowNull: false },
    species: { type: Sequelize.STRING, allowNull: false },
    homeworld: { type: Sequelize.STRING, allowNull: false }
  });

module.exports = EmpireModel;
```

For my thought, I want one data type that contain all of the Sequelize functions table manipulate functions (create, destroy, findAll, etc), and I *think* I want another data type that represents just the actual object involved (one particular Empire stored in the database). I could be completely wrong and am open to suggestions for how to make the above better.

The above code typechecks just fine, but I'm not really sure that `Class<Model<Empire>>` is the correct annotation for the return value from `sequelize.define`.

Now we get to the application itself:

```
// @flow

import Sequelize, { type Model } from "sequelize";
import { type Empire } from "./empire";

const sequelize = new Sequelize(
  "postgres://postgres:sequelize@localhost:5432/sqldemo"
);

const main = async () => {
  const EmpireModel: Class<Model<Empire>> = await require("./empire")(
    sequelize
  );
  const empire: Model<Empire> = await EmpireModel.create({
    name: "Sildaran Republic",
    species: "Sildar",
    homeworld: "Sakatarola"
  });

  const empires = await EmpireModel.findAll();
  console.log(empires);

  empires.map(empire => {
    console.log("[Empire]           ", empire.name);
    console.log("[Founding Species] ", empire.species);
    console.log("[Homeworld]        ", empire.homeworld);
  });
};
```

This code actually runs correctly, but the typechecker flags an error on the line `await Empires.findAll()`. The error message is

```
Cannot call await with `EmpireModel.findAll()` bound to `p` because:
 - Either cannot get `empire.name` because property `name` is missing in `Model` [1].
 - Or cannot call `empires.map` because property `map` is missing in `Promise` [2].

   src/index.js:20:25
     20|   const empires = await EmpireModel.findAll();
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

References:
   flow-typed/npm/sequelize_v4.x.x.js:3264:72
   3264|       options?: FindOptions<TAttributes & TCustomAttributes>): Promise<this[]>,
                                                                                ^^^^ [1]
   flow-typed/npm/sequelize_v4.x.x.js:3264:64
   3264|       options?: FindOptions<TAttributes & TCustomAttributes>): Promise<this[]>,
                                                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ [2]
```

So, I actually have a couple of specific questions:

1. What is the actual correct type to assign to `EmpireModel` in `empires.js`?
2. What is the actual type of return value of `await require("./empire")(sequelize);`, and how can I get Flow to break when I get it wrong (Flow is happy with whatever type I specify there and only flags errors later when I use that value in ways inconsistent with the type)

I am also open to all additional suggestions to make this code more correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer:

For some model `x`, you have to call `x.get()` or `x.toJSON()`<sup>1</sup> to get the plain object underlying the model. If you change the code after the query to

```
  empires.map(empire => empire.get())
         .map(empire => {
           console.log("[Empire]           ", empire.name);
           console.log("[Founding Species] ", empire.species);
           console.log("[Homeworld]        ", empire.homeworld);
         });
```

then it will work fine.

The long answer:

That solution may seem a little arbitrary, so here's the process that I used to find it. Unfortunately Flow's benefits come at the cost of learning its limitations and how to debug its error messages, so hopefully this pulls back the curtain a bit on how I do this.

The first thing I always check for is that the types are all imported correctly. The `flow-typed` directory is in the error message, as is the `Empire` type, so this looks good.

Next, the error message gives us two possibilities, and I want to figure out which one we're dealing with. Either `empires.map` is invalid, or `empire.name` is invalid. So I commented out the existing code in the `map` and replaced it with the identity function, `empire => empire`. When I did this the error went away, so it's clear that the problem is accessing `empire.name`.

To figure out why this is a problem, I dug into the libdef for Sequelize. It lives in the flow-typed repository [here](https://github.com/flow-typed/flow-typed/blob/master/definitions/npm/sequelize_v4.x.x/flow_v0.42.x-/sequelize_v4.x.x.js#L3076-L4147). Libdefs can look intimidating, but they're just normal flow definitions with the `declare` keyword added. In normal code you might say `let i : number = 1`, and with `declare` you would say

```
let i = 1;
declare i : number
```

The difference between these is that flow typechecks normal annotations to make sure they make sense, but it treats `declare` statements as gospel<sup>2</sup>. With this in mind, we can read the libdef itself to see what types and interfaces we're dealing with. Because libdefs use `declare`, the actual code inside of the Sequelize package is irrelevant to typechecking; Flow only looks at the libdef, not at the implementation.

There's pretty thorough documentation in the comments here, but unfortunately the file is over 7k lines long and doesn't put the most important definitions up top.

The declaration for the `Model` class lives [here](https://github.com/flow-typed/flow-typed/blob/master/definitions/npm/sequelize_v4.x.x/flow_v0.42.x-/sequelize_v4.x.x.js#L3076-L4147), and the definition of `findAll` lives [here](https://github.com/flow-typed/flow-typed/blob/master/definitions/npm/sequelize_v4.x.x/flow_v0.42.x-/sequelize_v4.x.x.js#L3260-L3261). We can see that `findAll` returns an array of type `this`, meaning an array that has the type `Model` with the same generic type parameters as our current `Model`. Going back to the top of `Model`, we see the following parameters:

```
Model<TAttributes, TInitAttributes = TAttributes, TPlainAttributes = TAttributes>
```

While the `Model` type takes 3 parameters, two of these are optional and set to the first parameter by default.

So our problem is that we're getting an array of objects with type `Model<Empire, Empire, Empire>`, we're mapping over it, and then we're trying to access the fields that are defined in the `Empire` type. In untyped JavaScript this is fine, because the library can dynamically add fields to a model, but in Flow, "merging" one object type with another like this requires using intersection types, and can have some rough edge cases. Fortunately, looking at the definition of `sequelize.define` later in the file shows that no such fancy thing is being done here. If we want to access the contained `Empire`, we need to find a method whose return value is one of the generic type parameters of `Model`.

We can see those [here](https://github.com/flow-typed/flow-typed/blob/master/definitions/npm/sequelize_v4.x.x/flow_v0.42.x-/sequelize_v4.x.x.js#L3985-L3987), and the last definition has all optional arguments, giving us the solution in the simple answer. Searching the rest of the class also turns up the [toJSON function.](https://github.com/flow-typed/flow-typed/blob/master/definitions/npm/sequelize_v4.x.x/flow_v0.42.x-/sequelize_v4.x.x.js#L4146)

---

<sup>1</sup> Note that `toJSON` returns an object, not a JSON string. When an object is passed into `JSON.stringify`, `stringify` will call the `toJSON` function on that object (if it is present) and will instead stringify the object that `toJSON` returns. This is why you can call `console.log` on a `Model` object and see the properties that you've defined on this model, and not all of the additional fields that Sequelize attaches to models. The name is misleading, but this is JavaScript's fault, not Sequelize's.

<sup>2</sup> Technically there is some checking. For instance, if you `declare` a variable to have both type `string` and `number`, you'll get an error. `declare` annotations are only checked for consistency with other `declare` annotations, and then non-`declare` annotations are checked against these, ensuring that if there's an error, it's reported as a problem with the normal annotations, not with the `declare` annotations.

Comment: This is a really impressively thorough answer and I'm likely to link to it in the documentation I'll attach to the real project.

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: I don't really know any Flow, and am coming to this with a TypeScript and Haskell background, and TypeScript unfortunately doesn't really have any light to shed on this (the output of `.define()` is just a `Model<Empire, Empire>` and it has an appropriate `.findAll()` method) -- but please do not consider me any more expert than that.

If I look at the [test suite](https://github.com/flow-typed/flow-typed/blob/master/definitions/npm/sequelize_v4.x.x/flow_v0.42.x-/test_sequelize.js) for the flow typings, they do not always use the [`Class<>` utility type](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/utilities/#toc-class) to type the output of `s.define()` but occasionally use `typeof`, and that seems to correspond to a desire to use subclasses:

```js
type WarehouseAttributes = {
  id?: number;
  address?: string;
  capacity?: number;
};

declare class WarehouseInstance extends Model<WarehouseAttributes> {
  id?: number;
  address?: string;
  capacity?: number;
  // ... mixins ...
};

// ... then this gets used to define ...

let Warehouse: typeof WarehouseInstance = s.define('warehouse', {});

// ... then this gets used to query ...

Warehouse
  .findAll({include: [{association: WarehouseProducts}]})]
  .then((warehouses: Array<WarehouseInstance>) => {})
```

Is it possible that such an approach allows you to return a declared class rather than a `Class<Model<EmpireAttributes>>` like you're doing right now? Maybe that is necessary to make the `Promise<this[]>` have a `this[]` which contains the `Empire` properties on that instance?

Comment: Through a debugging session, we just stumbled upon the idea that `Class<Model<EmpireModel>>` seems to correspond to the entire empires table, where `Model<EmpireModel>` seems to correspond to a single row, containing all of the instance methods plus the actual data fields that I care about. I don't know what kind of light that sheds upon things, yet.

Comment: Actually, it *doesn't* seem to contain the data fields. I mean, it does, but Flow doesn't seem to know that.